# My email banner-image appears saturated

Tags: color

Why does my banner image (in my email) appear saturated? Below is a screenshot of my email and the original image. I've never had this issue before.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a color profile issue.

Not all software will honor a color profile, but "it never happened before" probably indicates you exported the image differently.

I checked the original as listed in the source code, and it is a *CMYK JPEG*. These have limited support, especially in email programs: we used to have employees pick up print-ready CMYK Tiff files of objects to email to clients, but forget to change the color mode, and clients would either complain about not seeing anything or that the color looked funny/inverted etc.

At the least, reduce to the number of channels to RGB or export the image "for web."

In my experience, CMYK-on-RGB proofs tends to look saturated/excessively green and red, while RGB-on-CMYK proofs tend to look washed out.

Comment: As a side note, consider anonymizing your posting in the future: your employers might not appreciate exposing their content on a Q&A.

Comment: this makes sense... Sometime I forget to switch to RGB. thanks! : )